# Top 7 most common tags Taggit

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
def most_common(self):
    return self.get_queryset().annotate(
        num_times=models.Count(self.through.tag_relname())
        ).order_by('-num_times')
```

How would I edit this to only view the top 7 tags. This is a function from taggit and I would only like to see only 7. thanks.

Comment: How about `most_common()[:7]`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: List comprehension. That is override most_common()                                def most_common(self):
    return self.get_queryset().annotate(
        num_times=models.Count(self.through.tag_relname())
        ).order_by('-num_times')][:7]

Comment: @ozgur. Then it will query all and then get first 7 right. Wont the Isnt overriding a better option to reduce DB operation?

Comment: It is different than Python slicing the list. If you perform slicing on a queryset, Django does the *limiting* on db level so it doesn't evaluate the entire list. Please see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) for more information about limiting querysets.

Comment: Yes you are right we can use most_common()[:7]

Comment: thanks ozgur, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about most_common()[:7]?

```
YourModel.tags.most_common()[:7]
```

docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/… – ozgur

This is the correct asnwer, thanks ozgur